# How can I scale background image for mobile using CSS?

Tags: css, image, background-image

I'm trying to scale a background image on mobile devices such that the height is rescaled to be 100% of the device height, and the width is cropped as necessary to maintain the aspect ratio.

I'm currently using the following code to center and fix the image:

`background: url(redlineNoText.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;`

I've tried using `background-size: cover`, but it results in a very large image with only a small portion visible on a mobile browser.

I've also tried `background-size: auto 100%`, but it results in no background image.

For an example of the problem, please feel free to view [projectredline.org](http://www.projectredline.org/). The desktop view is what we're going for.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the units VH for viewport height and VW for viewport width.

A setting I often use for example is this one:

```
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
background: url(../images/hero.jpg);
background-size: cover;
background-position: center, center;
```

You could also use for example: `width: calc(100vw - 100px);` to come up with the perfect scale for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks!  Using vw and vh worked great. :) Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `background-attachment` might help you here?

```css
 html,body {
 height:100%;width:100% }    

 body {
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/1220x1100) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: auto auto;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 }

@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
  body {
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment:fixed }
}
```

```html
<body>

          <div>
          
                Content
          
          </div>

</body>
```